# mysql query - Count unique values in string in rows

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out how to count all of the unique instances of all strings in a column (multiple rows)

```
| fruit |

Apples, Grapefruit, Pears
Pears
Apples, Grapefruit
Apples
```

Query Output:

```
Apples: 3
Pears: 2
Grapefruit: 2
```

Comment: Denormalise your data structure and store each individual fruit value in its own record with a key referencing the main table. In that case it would be easy to do the count with `... count(distinct fruit) ... group by key` query.

Comment: Thanks Shadow - the link you provided did the trick, thanks!